# Excluding . and .. from results in find and ls

Tags: find, zsh, ls

Is there any way to prevent `find` and `ls -l` from listing `.` and `..` in their results? I never care about seeing this result in the output, and it prevents me from effectively piping their output to `wc -l` to count things accurately.

In case it matters, I am working in `zsh`.

Comment: You must have `ls` aliased to `ls -a` or something similar; `ls` does not include `.` or `..` by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
count() echo $#
count *        # non-hidden files (all types)
count *(D)     # files (all types)
count **/*(D)  # files recursively (all types)
count **/*(D/)  # directories only (recursively)
```

(`zsh` globs never include `.` nor `..` even when `dotglob` is enabled (like with the `(D)` globbing qualifier)).

To avoid an error message when there is no file, add the `N` globbing qualifier:

```
count *(ND)
```

That causes the glob to expand to nothing (no argument, not an empty argument) if there's no match.

Note that since the newline character is as valid a character as any in a file name, piping the output of `ls` or `find` to `wc -l` is not correct.

POSIXly, you could count the `/` characters instead of the newline ones:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -print | grep -c /
```

Or recursively, using this trick:

```
find .//. ! -name . -prune -print | grep -c //
```

Comment: This is great. One thing I noticed though is that if a folder has `0` files `count folder` outputs `no matches found`. Is there any way to make it return `0`?

Comment: @Josh, yes, use the `N` globbing qualifier (`nullglob`)

Answer (score 9):

For `ls`, use `-A` instead of `-a`.

from `man ls`:

```
   -A, --almost-all
          do not list implied . and ..
```

Answer (score 3):

To get `find` to exclude the dot directories you can use this:

```
$ find . ! -path . -type d
```

#### Example

```
$ find . ! -path . -type d | head -5
./.vim_SO
./.vim_SO/bundle
./.vim_SO/bundle/vim-fugitive
./.vim_SO/bundle/vim-fugitive/plugin
./.vim_SO/bundle/vim-fugitive/doc
...
```